# How to install pgstattuple extension in postgres 10.6?

Tags: postgresql

Can someone let me know how to install `pgstattuple` extension in postgres 10.6 running on Ubuntu 16?

I have installed `postgres-contrib` and can see the following `.sql` files under `extension` folder

```
ubuntu@vrni-proxy:~$ ls /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple*
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.0--1.1.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.3--1.4.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple.control
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.1--1.2.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.4--1.5.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.2--1.3.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.4.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a extension in PostgreSQL exist CREATE EXTENSION command.

Try:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;
```

In your database